# Erro na instalação do apache2

Tags: apache, ubuntu

Ao executar o comando `sudo apt-get install apache2` o seguinte erro é retornado:

```
Os pacotes a seguir têm dependências não satisfeitas:
apache2 : Depende: apache2-bin (= 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.9) mas não vai ser instalado
E: Não foi possível corrigir problemas, você tem pacotes mantidos (hold) estragados.
```

Como resolver o problema?

Já tentei os seguintes comandos para reparar pacotes quebrados e nada resultou:

```
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update
dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

A versão do Ubuntu é a 14.04 LTS.

Segue o arquivo /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento adicionei os dados a pergunta.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento fiz tanta coisa que já não me lembro de fato o que eu fiz! Eu já removi e reinstalei o apache2 / php várias vezes sem problemas, mas agora ocorre esse problema.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não, não ocorre nenhum erro.

Comment: Ocorreu esse erro: Falhou obter http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/i18n/Translation-en  Código de verificação hash não coincide

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento ok fiz isso, o erro que postei nos comentários não ocorre porém continua a dar o erro que inseri na pergunta.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento resolvi o problema. Além de utilizar o synaptic (obrigado pela dica), utilizei o comando "sudo aptitude install apache2".

Comment: posta como resposta, mesmo que bem simples a dica do `aptitude` é muito poderosa, eu nem lembrava desse comando :/

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu fiz o que você postou na resposta também e no fim fiz o `aptitude`. Pode complementar a sua resposta com essa dica, fica mais completa, assim marco como certa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abra o terminal e digite os seguintes comandos:

- Renomeie o sources.list atual (ou remova):

  ```
  sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.old
  ```
- Abra o programa *software-properties-gtk*:

  ```
  sudo software-properties-gtk
  ```

Isso foi para reiniciar o sources.list como na resposta do [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/124017), então selecione a opções como na imagem:

[image: software-properties-gtk setup]

Só que no *Download from* selecione *Other...* e procure pelo repositório de seu país (eu geralmente uso o Americano mesmo), isso vai gerar um novo `sources.list`.

Agora execute os seguintes comandos:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Talvez algumas coisas "importantes" sejam desinstaladas, mas você poderá reinstalar novamente.

Então tente executar o:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Se falhar novamente tente fazer o processo novamente, ao invés de usar o comando renomear faça o seguinte:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo mv /var/lib/apt/lists /var/lib/apt/lists.old
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

Então abra o *software-properties-gtk* e siga os mesmo passos citados anteriormente.